# Change UITabBarController selected index programmatically not working with 5 tabs

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I want to change selected index programmatically, but SOMETIMES it doesn't work; I'm prettry sure that these functions are called, inside the tab bar controller. Tested them together and one by one, too!

```
selectedIndex = 1
selectedViewController = viewControllers![1]
```

My TabBarController contains 5 tabs.

Comment: Make sure you are not returning false form tabbarShouldSelect delegate method

Comment: I have not implemented that method.

Comment: Did you try with other index or other view view controller is working ? like 2 , 3 or 4

Comment: And also try this tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![1] as UITabBarItem

Comment: Yes, Sometimes it works and sometimes not, It doesn't seem to be related to tab index, even.

Comment: Odd! I've found out my global varialbe that I hold my tabBarController inside it, is not referencing to my tabBarController correctly! I never change it and it's being set on viewDidLoad of my tabbarcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For click on particular button action:

```
- (IBAction)IndexBtnActn:(id)sender
{
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1] ;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any difference with what I have written, and I'm using the code inside the tab bar controller itself, so self.tabBarController is unnecessary.